# Loss of precision (assignment)

Tags: c++, c, lint

I am getting below warning for my code (some part of my code):

```
# define MN2DIV                    0x14                     
# define PLL_BASE_ADDRESS          0x481C5000                
# define ISS_PLL_BASE              (PLL_BASE_ADDRESS+0x140)                  
# define    M_PLL                 (volatile Uint32*)(ISS_PLL_BASE+MN2DIV)           

uint16 getfreqmhz(void)
{          
    uint16 M;          
    M= *M_PLL;           
}
```

- Note 923: cast from int to pointer [MISRA 2004 Rule 11.3]
- Info 734: Loss of precision (assignment) (32 bits to 16 bits)

I tried by casting like :  M= (uint16)*M_PLL ;
Cause of above changes the warning 734 got removed ,But I think this is not correct idea.

Can somebody tell me the correct way for doing this ....

Comment: Yes.:( ..Can you tell me any tool which will fix the MISRA warnings ....

Comment: I'm feeling MISRAble.

Answer (score 2):

**The key here is that you are interfacing with hardware for which you (presumably) have exacting specifications.**

If MISRA is a general-purpose static analyser, it won't be cognisant of the unique guarantees in your microcontroller environment. You're doing things that C++ doesn't like very much as a standard, because they don't make sense on (say) a PC. But, with sufficient information about the hardware and its interface, your code can be perfectly safe in practice; if so, you may ignore/suppress these diagnostics.

- The note is telling you about your `(volatile Uint32*)(ISS_PLL_BASE+MN2DIV)` (inside the macro), where you form a pointer from an integer.

  In any arbitrary C++ program I would agree with MISRA and say that this is bad form, but since you're specifying actual PLL locations that you know, it seems fine to me. I do it myself.

  So, you can safely ignore the note.
- The "info" is self-explanatory: the macro suggests that you treat each register location as a 32-bit word, but then you're trying to cram that value into 16 bits.

  Some possibilities:

  - this is wrong and each register is actually 16 bits;
  - `getfreqmhz` should return a `uint32`; or
  - or *you know for sure what you're doing is valid* based on some knowledge of the value range, and then your cast approach is fine.

Comment: Another possibility would be that the cast in the macro should really cast to uint16 ...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That's what I get for expanding "Either this wrong" incorrectly!

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a 32-bit value from PLL and storing it in a 16-bit variable. There are two cases:

1. You know for sure that the highest 16 bits of the value read from PLL are 0. In this case, ignore the warning (or remove it with a cast if you want), because the higher order 0s which you are not interested in are automatically dropped.
2. You are interested in the whole 32 bits of the value read from PLL. In that case, `M` should be `uint32` to be able to contain all of that data.

The first warning about cast from integer to pointer is for hosted code where casting integers to pointers is meaningless. In the microcontroller world, this is instead very meaningful when you are trying to access peripheral registers mapped to fixed addresses. Since you are on a microcontroller as it seems, ignore that warning.

Comment: If the OP is doing MISRA checking then I would assume that his application is safety-critical. There are reasons for the MISRA warnings and I think ignoring them is a very poor choice.

Comment: @JoeHass, if a microcontroller datasheet says the SPI status register is at address `0x504` and it's one byte, writing `#define SPI_STATUS *(uint8_t *)0x504` and then using `SPI_STATUS` in your code is perfectly fine. In fact, there is no other way around it. MISRA was written for hosted applications. Some of their rules may still apply in freestanding world, but for sure not all of them, as you can see in that example.

Comment: Actually, there _is_ a way around it: `#define SPI_STATUS *((uint8_t *)0 + 504)` but then you'd be just fooling yourself.

Comment: That said, MISRA itself is overprotective of the code. I believe MISRA assumes the programmer is a brick with no knowledge of the language itself and has rules to prevent any idiot from breaking anything. For example, if you have `uint16_t x = ...; uint8_t y = x >> 8;`, there is absolutely no reason for warning even though `x >> 8` has a greater type than `uint8_t`. Please, try not to blindly follow any rules (and not just in programming either).

Comment: I stand by my statement...you ignore MISRA rules at the risk of your career and the risk of those who rely on your code. Remember that critical code requires verification by another party...relying on tricks like this makes verification more difficult. Also, you ignore the possibility of code reuse. If your "known good" code gets used with a different architecture it can break in unpredictable ways. If you are writing code for toys, go ahead and ignore the warnings.

Comment: @JoeHass, you seem to misunderstand the context of the code. If you are coding for a microcontroller in which you need to access address `0x504` to read a certain register, there is nothing you can do but to cast that number to a pointer and read from it. If you move to another architecture, you have to change those numbers based on the new microcontroller. **This is not a _trick_, it's the actual proper way of doing it.**